# Replace NA with average of the case before and after the NA, unless row starts or ends with NA

Tags: r, replace, interpolation

Say I have a data.frame:

```
t<-c(1,1,2,4,NA,3) 
u<-c(1,3,4,6,4,2)
v<-c(2,3,4,NA,3,2)
w<-c(2,3,4,5,2,3)
x<-c(2,3,4,5,6,NA)
df<-data.frame(t,u,v,w,x)
df

   t u  v w  x
1  1 1  2 2  2
2  1 3  3 3  3
3  2 4  4 4  4
4  4 6 NA 5  5
5 NA 4  3 2  6
6  3 2  2 3 NA
```

I would like to change the NAs so that the NA becomes replaced by the average of the one value before the NA and the one value after the NA. However, if a row starts with an NA I would like it to be replaced by the value that follows it. When a row ends with NA, I would like it to be replaced by the value before the NA. Thus, I would like to get the following result:

```
   t u  v   w  x
1  1 1  2   2  2
2  1 3  3   3  3
3  2 4  4   4  4
4  4 6  5.5 5  5    --> NA becomes average of 6 and 5
5  4 4  3   2  6    --> NA becomes value of next case  
6  3 2  2   3  3    --> NA becomes value of previous case
```

I have thousands of rows, so any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on previous `na.approx` solutions this might do the trick:

```
library(zoo)
t(apply(df, 1,function(x) na.approx(x,rule=2)))
```

Comment: This did indeed do the trick! You are a true hero.

Comment: I get this error `Error in na.approx(x, rule = 2) : could not find function "na.approx"`

Comment: `library(zoo)` please. Include that

Comment: @Sotos yes, included!

Answer (score 0):

Always search for parameter na.rm = T in functions that you use.
In this case you want to use mean of one of the column with the na.rm param set to true.
Then you want to substitute NA-s.

```
dt[is.na(dt[,'t']),'t'] = 0
```

(assuming that I did not reverse the order of dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution,

if is NA replace with (lag + lead) /2 if still NA replace with lag if still NA replace with lead.

```
library(dplyr)
t(apply(df, 1, function(x){
     lagx = dplyr::lag(x)
     leadx = dplyr::lead(x)
     b = ifelse(is.na(x),(leadx+lagx)/2, x)
     b = ifelse(is.na(b), leadx, b)
     b = ifelse(is.na(b), lagx, b)
     return(b)
     }
))
#output
     t u   v w x
[1,] 1 1 2.0 2 2
[2,] 1 3 3.0 3 3
[3,] 2 4 4.0 4 4
[4,] 4 6 5.5 5 5
[5,] 4 4 3.0 2 6
[6,] 3 2 2.0 3 3
```

Comment: This also works! Thanks!!

Comment: @Hardik gupta the column is just rounded to one decimal since one imputed value has one decimal, same happens if you just `df[4,3] = 5.5` in the starting data.

Answer (score 0):

```
t<-c(1,1,2,4,NA,3) 
u<-c(1,3,4,6,4,2)
v<-c(2,3,4,NA,3,2)
w<-c(2,3,4,5,2,3)
x<-c(2,3,4,5,6,NA)
df<-data.frame(t,u,v,w,x)

df[which(is.na(t)), "t"] <- df[which(is.na(t)), "u"]
df[which(is.na(x)), "x"] <- df[which(is.na(x)), "w"]
df[which(is.na(v)), "v"] <- (df[which(is.na(v)), "u"] + df[which(is.na(v)), "w"])/2

> df
  t u   v w x
1 1 1 2.0 2 2
2 1 3 3.0 3 3
3 2 4 4.0 4 4
4 4 6 5.5 5 5
5 4 4 3.0 2 6
6 3 2 2.0 3 3
```